# Mass compare records

Tags: csv

I have a CSV file which has some 5k records. I want to check if those records are present in my SFDC org or not. Is there any way/tool available other than extracting the data and doing vLookup?

Comment: If the record is in Salesforce do you want to do an update? if not do an insert? You could use the Upsert function in the DataLoader app

Comment: I don't have to do any DML. I just wanted to check whether the records present in my CSV are there in SFDC or not.

Comment: First thing should be how you define 'is present in Salesforce'.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

No.

---

Still quite a short answer:

You need to get the data in the same format - either both SFDC records or both CSV.

Personally I would export to CSV and vlookup as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody. This was one time export so I used the trial version of Demand Tools to get the data out if the Salesforce. It was super easy.